# how to click on a link that loads ajax data using selenium and python

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract some data from a site which loads the data using ajax and I am using selenium along with python for this.I want to click on a link which appears after an ajax page load.
I have even put sleep function of python so that the page loads completely, but still not able to click. This error comes every time "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element".Please see the following code which I have written.
Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import subprocess
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:/Users/212553509/Desktop/WHO"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "C:/python27/Scripts/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("http://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.home")
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('node.main.484?lang=en').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a WebDriverWait so that Selenium has a chance to repeatedly poll the page to look for your element:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html

Comment: Thanks.. but the wait isn't working either. The table is not visible on the source code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the link `href`, not the link text to `driver.find_element_by_link_text`. If you have HTML code like this

```
<a target="_top" href="node.main.MEDSMDG8?lang=en">Essential medicines</a>
```

Use `driver.find_element_by_text('Essential medicines')`

Comment: Thanks! but I tried this also. can you suggest any other libraries using which I can fetch the data which is visible on the page but not in the source code

Comment: You can try scraperJs - I find it a lot easier to use compared to Python + Selenium.